# How do I merge my imputed data with my original dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe

I am working through the titanic kaggle problem and one of the things I am looking to do is use sklearn's IterativeImputer to fill in my missing values.

I am hitting a roadblock after I run the imputation and generate my "filled" values. I am wondering how best to update the original dataframe with the filled values.

## Code:

```
from sklearn.experimental import enable_iterative_imputer  
from sklearn.impute import IterativeImputer

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

titanic = pd.DataFrame(
    {
     "PassengerId": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
     "Survived": [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
     "PClass": ['3', '1', '3', '1', '3'],
     "Name": ['Braund, Mr. Owen Harris', 'Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)',
              'Heikkinen, Miss. Laina', 'Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)', 'Allen, Mr. William Henry'],
     "Sex": ['male', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'male'],
     "Age": [22, 38, 26, np.nan, 35],
     "SibSp": [1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
     "Parch": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     "Fare": [7.25, 71.2833, 7.925, 53.1, 8.05]
     }
    )

# Slicing dataframe to feed to imputer
titanic_sliced = titanic.loc[:, ['Age', 'SibSp', 'Parch', 'Fare']]
titanic_sliced.head()
```

## Output of sliced dataset:

```
        Age  SibSp  Parch     Fare
0  22.0      1      0   7.2500
1  38.0      1      0  71.2833
2  26.0      0      0   7.9250
3   NaN      1      0  53.1000
4  35.0      0      0   8.0500
```

## Run imputer with a Random Forest estimator

```
imp = IterativeImputer(RandomForestRegressor(), max_iter=10, random_state=0)
imputed_titanic = pd.DataFrame(imp.fit_transform(titanic_sliced), columns=titanic_sliced.columns)
imputed_titanic
```

## Output of imputed_titanic:

```
       Age  SibSp  Parch     Fare
0  22.00    1.0    0.0   7.2500
1  38.00    1.0    0.0  71.2833
2  26.00    0.0    0.0   7.9250
3  36.11    1.0    0.0  53.1000
4  35.00    0.0    0.0   8.0500
```

So now my question is, what is the best way to update the original dataframe with the imputed values?

Comment: This is not a MRE: your posted code fails to run, as you failed to initialize your data frame.

Comment: @Prune I'm sure you're probably annoyed with me by now but thanks again. I realized now I was being quite lazy with my initial ask. I've actually learned quite a bit just getting my question into proper format. I ran the updated code and it reproduces exactly what I expect.

Comment: That's the idea: learn from mistakes, do better next time.  So long as you're trying to improve, we're happy to work with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to user Prune I was able to figure this out. I am not sure this is the best method but in my instance the solution was quite simple. Because the order of my data before and after imputation were the same, I was able to use the combine_first to update my data while retaining the rest of the non-missing values.

I don't believe this is ideal as this may not always be the case, I would like to further develop this out to make it "smarter" (ie. be able to specify which values to impute or somehow include an index/join key).

Here is the code I ultimately used:

```
df3= titanic.combine_first(imputed_titanic)
df3.head()
```

**Output:**

```
 Age Cabin Embarked     Fare                                               Name  Parch  PassengerId  Pclass     Sex  SibSp  Survived            Ticket
0  22.0   NaN        S   7.2500                            Braund, Mr. Owen Harris      0            1       3    male      1         0         A/5 21171
1  38.0   C85        C  71.2833  Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Th...      0            2       1  female      1         1          PC 17599
2  26.0   NaN        S   7.9250                             Heikkinen, Miss. Laina      0            3       3  female      0         1  STON/O2. 3101282
3  35.0  C123        S  53.1000       Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)      0            4       1  female      1         1            113803
4  35.0   NaN        S   8.0500                           Allen, Mr. William Henry      0            5       3    male      0         0            373450
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't, as given.  You destroyed the data for the required location.  Instead, you have to maintain that data in some way.  I recommend that you transfer the index to a simple data column, where you can recover it later.

Comment: I gave this a shot and it works well but including the index will affect the imputation result, is there a way to do this without considering the index column for imputation?

Comment: We can't tell, and you neglected to include the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  When I've run into this problem, I've simply held onto the original data frame, done the imputation without the interfering data, and then matched the result according to *other* values in the original DF.  Even more effective is to use an imputation routine that is smart enough to let you specify which columns are involved.

Comment: Sorry, thought my original post contained the relevant code to reproduce, but as I got more specific I realized I should have included the code. Thanks for the suggestions. As I am still new to this I will do what you suggested, match back using the other values. I would love to get to a point where I can implement your latter suggestion, but for learning I will hold off.

Comment: Check the suggestions for an MRE again.  [Include your minimal data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246/how-to-provide-a-reproducible-copy-of-your-dataframe-with-to-clipboard) as part of the example.  Your code dies because there's no `train.csv` file.  The question dies because you haven't shown the stages of processing.

Comment: Updated the question based on the suggestions you shared and the MRE guide you linked. Would appreciate any feedback on improvements I can still make to my question. I recognize that you've already gone above and beyond here though, thanks very much for both answering my question and helping me understand how to properly ask questions here.